# Deleting a person from a file not in a list

Tags: python, file

For class I need to put names into a file then have the user type in the name they want to delete, and it deletes them. I almost have it it just deletes 2 people at once and I'm not sure why.

```
import os
def main():
  found=False
  search=input("Who would you like to delete? ")
  student_grades = open("student_grades.txt", 'r')
  temp_file= open('temp.txt', 'w')
  descr = student_grades.readline()

  while descr != '':
    qty = (student_grades.readline())

    descr = descr.rstrip('\n')

    if descr != search:
      temp_file.write(descr + '\n')
      temp_file.write(str(qty) + '\n')
    else:
      found = True
    descr = student_grades.readline()

  student_grades.close()
  temp_file.close()

  os.rename('temp.txt', 'grades.txt')

  if found:
    print('The file has been updated.')
  else:
    print('That student was not found in the file.')

main()
```

There is also 2 files. student_grades.txt that has the names in it, and temp.txt with nothing. When typing in the name of the person, it can find them but it deletes 2 people instead of the one that was searched.

Comment: Please share your input file

Comment: Are you sure it deletes two people? This `qty = (student_grades.readline()) ... temp_file.write(str(qty) + '\n')` makes me think that you might be adding unwanted new lines (no `strip` when getting the `qty`, but adding a new line when rewriting it), which might look like you removed two instead of one?
`

Comment: Eraw got it. I just deletes those 2 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3.6+

```
from pathlib import Path
fname = "student_grades.txt"
def bak_file(old_name, new_name=None):
    if new_name is None:
        new_name = old_name + '.bak'
    Path(new_name).write_bytes(Path(old_name).read_bytes())
    print('-->', f'cp {old_name} {new_name}')

def main():
    bak_file(fname)
    lines = Path(fname).read_text().splitlines()
    search = input("Who would you like to delete? ").strip()
    if search in lines:
        updated_lines = [i for i in lines if i != search]
        Path(fname).write_text('\n'.join(updated_lines))
        print(f'The file {fname} has been updated.')
    else:
        print('That student was not found in the file.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it deletes two people? This qty = (student_grades.readline()) ... temp_file.write(str(qty) + '\n') makes me think that you might be adding unwanted new lines (no strip when getting the qty, but adding a new line when rewriting it), which might look like you removed two instead of one?

Eraw got it. It works now. I was following a program from my book and they had a slightly different scenario. I deleted `qty = (student_grades.readline())` and `temp_file.write(str(qty) + '\n')` and this deletes only what needs to be deleted. Thanks!